# Manga about girl adopted mage girl

Tags: story-identification, manga

The manga or it may have been a maunha was about a girl who was treated poorly in her family being adopted by another family she because famous at the border as a powerful mage and returns to the capital I read it a while ago and it only had a 4 chapter wanted to find it again and see ignore was out

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When was a while ago?  Last month?  Last year?  You could also improve your question by breaking it into proper sentences; it's very difficult to read.

Comment: This is pretty tropey. Off the top of my head it fits *[Daughter of the Archmage](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/daughter-of-the-archmage)* and *[I Belong to House Castielo](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/i-belong-to-house-castielo)* but not perfectly